# How to animate or use transitions on a message pop up with javascript and css?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I currently have the message displaying and disappearing as I want but the transition isn't working, This is what I tried.

```js
const alertMsg = document.querySelector('.alert');
contactForm.addEventListener('submit', formSubmitted);


function formSubmitted(e) {
  //other stuff

  alertMsg.style.display = 'block';
  setTimeout(() => {
    alertMsg.style.display = 'none';
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
.alert {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">Your message has been sent, I will get back to you as soon as possible.</div>
```

The message just instantly disappears and reappears, how can I use the transition currently to make some sort of animation?

This is my first question so sorry if I missed any information out, I will add any more if needed. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't** transition (or animate) the display property. the `display` property is either *on* or *off* there's nothing to transition or animate.

What you can do is animate **opacity** and alter the display property at start and end.

something like:

```
@keyframes showBlock {
    from { display: block; opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes hideBlock {
   from { opacity: 1; }
   to { opacity: 0; display: none; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I switched out the opacity for display on my current code and it works now but I haven't used keyframes before, how would I call that keyframe with my current structure? in the javascript or/and css div?

Comment: Hi @nameless Here's far more information about CSS animations than I could possibly provide here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations